# Windup tool for windows m/c

Tags: windows, unix, jboss, websphere, rhamt

I want to know whether we can install and run the WindUp tool in windows m/c. If so can anyone explain me the steps.

and one more thing is,

I have the  war file of my application with me and I want to migrate the application server(i.e, WebSphere ) to JBoss using WindUp tool. I have no idea how to do and what needs to be changed.

Can anyone explain me how can I do this migration from WebSphere to J-boss using WindUp tool in windows m/c and in Unix m/c.

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can run Windup on Windows, provided you have Java 7 installed.
You simply download it and run against your application's archive.
See here:

https://github.com/windup/windup/wiki/Execute

I don't know what you mean by "windows m/c".